# Curve Fitting Metrics: Mean Percent Difference

Tags: regression, forecasting, curve-fitting, metric, rms

I recently discovered my colleague (not a mathematician) was evaluating their experimental regression analyses by reporting the mean percent difference of each estimated output (from their fitted curve) with the true output.

My instincts would be to evaluate goodness of fit with root mean squared error.

Is my colleague's method of evaluating fitted curves superior, or are there reasons supporting RMSE?